# How to focus on treeview children

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, children

My table has a parent's row and a children's row.

When I selected the children's row and deleted children.

After that the table switches and focuses on the parent's row.

My question is how to keep focus on the children row.

Remark:

I have tried like this:

```
children = tree.getchildren()
table.focus(children)
```

Anyway its not effective.

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre].